# How to solve difficult exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, transcendental-equations

I would like to know how can I solve the following exponential equation for $x$:
$$\exp\left(\frac{n_1}{x}\right) + \exp(n_2) + \exp\left(n_3 - \frac{n_4}{x}\right) - \exp(n_5) = 0$$
where $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, $n_4$, and $n_5$ are constants.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you'll have to solve numerically, if there is even a solution. Do you know the $n_i$'s?

Comment: For some integer values of the $n_i$, the equation can be multiplied by $e^{nx}$ for some $n$ and then solved as a polynomial in $e^x$, though in general this will not yield a closed-form solution.

Comment: Yes, I know $n_i$'s. So what is the best way to solve it? There is no possibility for a closed-form solution?

Comment: The killer is $n_3$ Without that, you can get an equation of the form $a^x=b$ and take logs.

Comment: the value for $n_1/n_4$ depends on the values I use, but it is probably greater than 1 and less than 4.

Comment: I apologize, I just realized I did not write the equation correctly. Please see the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=\exp(1/x)$ and $n_i'=\exp(n_i)$ and multiply both sides by $y^{n_4}$ to get

$$y^{n_1+n_4}+(n_2'-n_5')y^{n_4}+n_3'=0$$

which is a trinomial in $y$, which cannot be algebraically solved in general. It can, of course, be solved numerically.

Comment: Nice answer! How can you prove that your equation cannot be algebraically solved? Thanks.

Comment: [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) e.g. $y^5-y+1=0$ cannot be solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I solve it numerically?

Comment: @IgorDakic There are plenty of [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) you can see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Just one last question - it is possible to do an approximation of this equation and have some formulation for $x$? It does not have to be exact.

Comment: @IgorDakic Not clear what you mean.